# Inflating a child layout and parent layout is clickable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, layout-inflater

I have a login screen with username,password edittext  and login Button. On login a layout is inflated over the login screen.

If I touch the inflated layout, the parent layout (Login screen) gets clickable due to which keyboard appears if I click on position of edittext. Is there any solution for my problem. I hav to apply Swipe Screen on my Inflated Layout so it has to be clickable.

I have google a lot but cannot find suitable help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the above layout to be clickable, it will then intercept touch event.
In your xml with `android:clickable="true"` or by code with `view.setClickable(true)`.